# Foreign Key Constraint Violation with Django and Postgres

Tags: django, mongodb, postgresql, migration

I am getting a foreign key constraint violation between two models in Django 1.7 when I try to populate the data.

The first model is Specialty, a simple name placeholder, which looks like this:

```
class Specialty(MongoidModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

The model that references it, Job, looks like this:

```
class Job(MongoidModel):
    specialty = models.ForeignKey(
        Specialty,
        null=True,
        blank=True
     )
```

Both of these inherit MongoidModel, which is just a custom model that contains an id, a created_at date and an updated_at date, for the purposes of porting data in from the original Mongo database.

Makemigrations runs fine, as does migrate, but when I actually try to port in all the Job objects, I immediately get this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "jobs_job" 
violates foreign key constraint "D76699ba021e613d02bad10e8fb41f69"
DETAIL:  Key (specialty_id)=(None) is not present in table
"specializations_specialty".
```

Looking at the specific job that causes the crash reveals that it contains a None for the specialty, since many jobs don't have specialties.

It's my understanding that the database is trying to find a specialty object with id None, and failing. I thought that this is what the blank=True and null=True in the ForeignKey definition was supposed to gracefully avoid, by not letting it get to that state, and just letting the association lie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the answer was in the way that I was creating the models. When I had a Writer come in with a None as their Specialty, I was still passing that field:

```
{'writer_name': 'Bob', 'specialty_id':None}
```

to the object mapper/object creator, and django was looking for a None as the key in the Specialty table. The correct thing to do was to check whether specialty_id was a None, and then exclude it from the mapper/object creator all together:

```
{'writer_name': 'Bob'}
```

Thanks for the helpful comments, I learned a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Similar errors can be received if trying to save related models through overridden model or admin save methods. Without seeing your full model or admin code this is just a stab in the dark, but django-modelcluster may provide the cascading save structure you need.

> **django-modelcluster** introduces a new type of relation, ParentalKey, where the related models are stored locally to the
>   ‘parent’ model until the parent is explicitly saved.

To use it, import the ParentalKey model field type and use it like a FK.

```
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey

class Job(MongoidModel):
    specialty = ParentalKey(
        Specialty,
        null=True,
        blank=True
     )
```

The possibility exists that the constraint "D76699ba021e613d02bad10e8fb41f69" was created by the Mongo library through an error. Not having used MongoDB for Django projects I don't have many details for that, but through Mongo itself you are able to go and delete contraint "D76699ba021e613d02bad10e8fb41f69" from the db. Since Mongo doesn't use traditional fk's as far as I know, I assume the constraint is a simple not-null and deleting it would solve it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Does this work if you switch your DB to Sqlite3?
2. Are you sure you've run `manage.py makemigrations specialty` and `manage.py migrate`? Otherwise, there might be a stale constraint.